# Response does not match (although it match)

Tags: java, rest

Could someone assist in asserting following:

```
String Givencoordinates = "[[-45.85112, 18.17335], [-45.85164, 18.173283], [-45.85283, 18.17247]]"
```

Want to assert above string with following code:

```
given()
    .get(apiUrl)
    .then()
    .assertThat()
    .body(“angle", equalTo(Collections.singletonList(120)))
    .body("coordinates", equalTo((Collections.singletonList(Givencoordinates)));
```

The first step (body - angle) is passing, but for a second, getting the following error:

```sh
JSON path coordinates doesn't match.
Expected: <[[-45.85112, 18.17335], [-45.85164, 18.173283], [-45.85283, 18.17247]]>
Actual: [[-45.85112, 18.17335], [-45.85164, 18.173283], [-45.85283, 18.17247]]
```

Tried with (**Collections.singletonList(Givencoordinates)** & with **(Arrays.asList(Givencoordinates)**, in assertion, but getting same error.

What could be solution for this error? Thank you

Comment: there is still a `.` at the end of the code, did you paste the whole assert statement?

Comment: @CodeMatrix I saw it. Copy-paste error. Fixed

Comment: Are you trying to compare a string to an arraylist? `Arrays.asList(Givencoordinates)` shouldn't compile

Comment: @OneCricketeer What you propose to do? Although it does work for above step, where only one value is asserted (angle) which is not list

Comment: We don't know what types of data your api actually returns, but if you're actually getting a 2D json array back (not a string), and need to compare that response to something, it should be defined as a `double[][]` or `List<List<Double>>`, not a `String`

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thank you it solved my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Junit output is calling `toString` on your data

You should try to define the expected value as an actual list rather than putting a single string into a list of one element